# Efficient haircuts

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, time-complexity, sorting, priority-queues

I have a real vector $v$.  From this vector, I want to extract a sequence of integers, $ix$.  The first integer is found by, $ix_0=argmax(v)$.  1 is then subtracted from $v_{ix_0}$, and the process is repeated until all elements of v are less than 0.

The following pseudo-Python function does this.

```
def countdown(v):
    ix = []
    while True:
        ix_t = argmax(v)
        if v[ix_t]>0:
            v[ix_t]-=1
            ix.append(ix_t)
        else:
            break
    return ix
```

BUT, it is inefficient, because the argmax does a new scan over all the elements of v on every step.  It seems like there must be a better way to represent v so that we can efficiently check what the new argmax should be without scanning over the whole vector from scratch.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: use a heap. Better hint: sort the vector.

Answer (score 3):

The exercise wants you to use a priority queue (also known as a heap). I'll let you figure out how this helps.

If the input were integral, then you could do even better by sorting the list. This might still work even in the general case, but requires more work. (You might need to sort both the values themselves and their fractional parts.)

Comment: Edit: Thanks for the pointers.  As I understand it (if we say S is the sequence length and N is the vector length), both the heap and sorting solutions take O(NlogN+S) time in the average case.  If the average sequence is very small (few elements are >0), then the argmax approach is more efficient: O((S+1)*N).  I'm wondering if there's a solution that gracefully degrades from taking O((S+1)*N) time in the case of a very short sequence to O(NlogN+S) time in the case of a longer sequence.

Comment: You should add this discussion to the question itself.